# Laravel 5.1 Session not working

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.1

i have Session in my Controller store

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
\Session::push('store_pos.items',$request->all());
print_r(\Session::get('store_pos.items')); // This is show array
exit;
}

public function create()
{
$items = \Session::get('store_pos.items');
print_r($items); // in this syntax not show array
}
```

why session in function create not show ? 
I've been using the session put but still does not appear

Thanks

Comment: what function you call first? .

Comment: everytime you call `\Session::get('store_pos.items');` is always empty because the store method hasn't been call yet.

Comment: Can you give me sample ? please :(

Comment: I want to know what you are trying to achieve? so maybe I can help you with better approach or answer.

Comment: I make a transaction form, when in refresh page value in form transaction not lost

Comment: let me make it clearer. You want to make a transaction form when user submit the form and successfully save, it redirect back to the form with the input?. Is this correct?

Comment: if error transaction then refresh page form input not lost,

Comment: already solved hehe thank you :D in session create i change to pull and working

Comment: great to here that. I post an answer maybe it helped you with better approach ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you want to return the input if anything error when you submit the form:

```
$trans = new Transaction();
// Do all the input stuff

if($trans->save()){
// your code if the transaction successfully save
}

return back()->withInput(); // this will return back to the page with input

//or if  you prefer facade

return Redirect::back()->withInput();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your controller under "web" middleware?

Any routes not placed within the web middleware group will not have access to sessions and CSRF protection, so make sure any routes that need these features are placed within the group.